# Hibernate - Search text in all columns of table

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

Lets say we have this table:

```
id | name | note |
------------------
1  | bb   | abc  |
2  | bc   | bcd  |
3  | ac   | cde  |
```

I want to get all rows which contains `a` in any column of table.

Result should be `1 - bb - abc` and `3 - ac - cde`

How I can done this using Hibernate or SQL? (I prefer to done this without mentioning columns name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you simply need to use [`LIKE %..%`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) match for all the columns with `OR` condition:

```sql
SELECT * FROM your_table_name 
WHERE name LIKE '%a%' 
      OR note LIKE '%a%'
```

Comment: There is no way without mentioning columns?

Comment: @KunLun No, unless you prepare a Dynamic SQL, but that would be way more cumbersome and at the end of the day, it will also prepare a SQL string containing all the columns name(s) (dynamically)

Comment: @KunLun Is this searching activity a one time thing ? If yes, then PHPMyAdmin provides a search across all the columns without specifying them explicitly. PHPMyAdmin internally fetches the names of all the columns using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, and then prepares the dynamic query

Comment: What do you mean by `"Is this searching activity a one time thing"`?

Comment: @KunLun I mean if you need to do this query only once (generally it is done to look for some data, or fix some data etc), then you can do this in PHPMyAdmin, without specifying all the column names individually

Comment: I have an Spring App(Java) where I have an input search and I want to bring data from database based on what is typed in input on website. But I can get field names without a problem. But I have a feeling like is not best solution.(just feeling :D)

Comment: @KunLun if these columns are mostly text type; then you can also use Full Text Search for better performance; also you can all the columns in a single Full Text Index